# We are *close* to getting answers to the following questions:

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Based on the comments, some progress has been made in the following questions. In many cases, people have indicated that they know the answer, and/or people have encouraged some of the commenters to turn their comments into answers.

In such cases, one thing you can do to help is to further encourage people to write answers, or even write an answer yourself if you think you can, after so much progress was made in the comment chain (which might help you to write an answer).

The list is presented in an answer to this post, in Community Wiki format so that users can edit it if they find more such questions, or they can strike items off the list if the question does become answered.

Answer (score 4):

Feel free to add to this list, it's a Community Wiki! Please add questions to the *bottom* of this list, and given each question a *permanent* numerical identifier so that we never have to do any re-numbering when a question does manage to graduate from this list:

- <s>(1) [Is it possible to construct a tight binding matrix of high atomic layer thin film from the lower one?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4653/5) (turn the comments into a Community Wiki?)</s>
- <s>(2) [How to fix gauge in Quantum ESPRESSO?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4365/5)</s>
- <s>(3) [References related to the molecular distance geometry problem (estimating true distances based on noisy distances)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/5088/5)</s>
- <s>(4) [Wavefunction magnitudes being degenerate everywhere on parameter space even though energy degeneracies occur at isolated points?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4974/5)</s>
- <s>(5) [Is there an example in which TD-DFT was successful in describing photophysical or photochemical processes?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4443/5)</s>
- <s>(6) [How to treat delocalized pi bonds in DFT](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/7194/5)</s>
- <s>(7) [Two-stage unbinding & binding energies with DFT](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4361/5)</s>
- <s>(9) [Benchmarking Monte Carlo simulations of polymers](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/7059/5)</s>
- <s>(10) [How to show electrostatic interactions in Pymol or other on the wanted residue](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6987/5)</s>
- <s>(11) [How to look for specific structural motifs in proteins?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6951/5)</s>
- <s>(12) [Is it possible to build a force field that suits all elements based on VASP's machine learning result?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9145/5) (jheindel's comments are basically the answer)</s>

- <s>(12) [Space group issue with XYZ, VASP formats in VESTA](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8715/5)</s>
- (13) [Cheap NMR shift calculations in periodic systems](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8724/5)
- <s>(14) [How to calculate the surface area of a stepped surface slab in a unit cell?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8680/5)</s>
- <s>(15) [Changing global cartesian coordinate system with VESTA](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8725/5)</s>
- <s>(16) [How to calculate circular dichroism in VASP?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8672/5)</s>
- <s>(17) [How to start with the elastic properties of 2D materials using the VASP code?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8624/5)</s>
- (18) [Database of surface electronic structure](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8572/5) (Nike can probably answer it)
- <s>(19) [Optimizing (DFT/MP2) small molecule dimers](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8920/5)</s>
- <s>(20) [DOS projection in alternate axis for eg and t2g contributions](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6787/5)</s>
- <s>(21) [Minimum number of kpoints for calculation of properties of nanoparticles in vasp](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8796/5)</s>
- (22) [Problem while performing the BSE GW calculations in VASP](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8938/5)
- (23) [Can the electrical conductivity tensor of a crystal be obtained from a Hartree-Fock calculation?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9245/5)
- <s>(24) [How to gain an understanding of Material Science topics?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9290/5) (Nike can probably answer it)</s>
- <s>(25) [Total force calculated with cp2k not zero](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9299/5) (Phil's comment might be good enough of an answer)</s>
- (26) [Installation of GaussView on Linux Ubuntu 20.04.2 ARM](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9406/5)
- (27) [Gaussian Job File with Variables and Link1](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9421/5)
- (28) [Validity of estimating electron relaxation time using the smallest cross section of a structure](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8444/5)
- (29) [Continuous Coordination Number Definition](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9281/5)
- (30) [Interface between metadynamics and LAMMPS](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10133/5)
- (31) [Continuous Coordination Number Definition](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9281/5)
- (32) [How is temperature changes implemented in a molecular dynamics simulation?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9922/5)
- (33) [What files are important while taking backup of a VASP calculation?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11043/5) (CW Tan)

---

- <s>(1) [Transition dipole moment derivative TURBOMOLE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8595/5) (might be possible to get answered by asking someone from TURBOMOLE)</s>
- <s>(2) [Evaluating Coulomb and exchange integrals in practice using cartesian coordinates](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8591/5) (might be possible to get an answer by JJGoings).</s>
- <s>(3) [Error while installing ShengBTE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6412/5) (might be possible to get an answer by asking the developers).</s>
- <s>(4) [Constructing a molecular polarizability tensor from sets of atomic polarizabilities?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8636/5) (seems the answer might be available via a thorough enough literature search)</s>

Comment: Question numbers 2,14,15,28 are closed. So do closed questions still remain in this list?

Comment: @VandanRevanur thanks for noticing that! If there's any closed questions that you or anyone else would like to answer, you can always click "flag" then type a custom message, saying that you would like the question to be re-opened so that you can answer it. Maybe separate from the above list, we can create another list of "closed" questions that are likely to get answered. If you'd like to make that list (starting with 2,14,15,28) you're welcome to do that!

Comment: I think it wouldn’t make sense to make a list of closed questions since anyone can express interest by clicking flag like you mentioned. So my proposal is to just remove those questions from this list.

Comment: It might be helpful to have them all grouped together in one central place though, since it would make them easier to find. These low-hanging-fruit questions have already been "found" so I don't see the need to "un-find" them :)

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I will make a list of such questions.

Comment: Now I added the list [here](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402/we-are-on-the-brink-of-getting-answers-to-the-following-closed-questions/403#403)